# jquery simple help for beginner

Tags: jquery

how to make multiple input type text when the blur of and the input type text generate input type text as the result of enter value in input type text .. with div and label ?

My JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#noans').blur(function(){
            var html = '<input type="text" name="noans" id="noans" class="txtbx required" />';
        });
    });
</script>
```

My html:

```
<div class="fldset">
    <label for="noans">No Of Answers:</label>
    <input type="text" name="noans" id="noans" class="txtbx required" />
</div>
<div class="fldset" id="adans"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Form your input field wanted to dynamically generate and append them under the component locating by Id.

```
 $('#noans').blur(function(){
                 var html = '<input type="text" name="noans1" id="noans1" class="txtbx required" />';
                 $("#mydiv").append(html);
    });
```

In Html file

```
<div id="mydiv" class="fldset">
    <label for="noans">No Of Answers:</label>
    <input type="text" name="noans" id="noans" class="txtbx required" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend using '`change`' event binding instead of '`blur`'. Once you do that, you need to then check whether the entered value is a valid number or not. Once thats verified, you can iterate through a for loop ( for the sake of simplicity ) and create the elements dynamically and append it to the div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#noans').change(function(){
   if(isNaN(parseInt(this.value)))
   {
      alert("not a valid number");
      return;
   }
   var value = this.value;
   $("#adans").empty();
   $("#adans").append("<br/>");
   for(var i=1; i <= this.value; i++)
   {

     var lblele = $("<label/>",{
                  text : 'Answer ' + i
                 });
     var Inele = $("<input/>",{
                  type: 'text',
                  name: 'noans',
                  id : "noans" + i,
                  'class': 'txtbx required'
               });
         $("#adans").append(lblele);
         $("#adans").append(Inele);  
         $("#adans").append("<br/>");
   }
});
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/x427qn59/2/